# How to import .vsd format in mxgraph grapheditor

Tags: javascript, import, mxgraph

I have a .vsd file. I want to import the same in mxgraph grapheditor tool. I am not able to do that.

I customised the grapheditor tool as per my requirement and now i want the implement .vsd file import in that tool.

Can anyone help me with a way to do that.

I saw the same being implemented in draw.io and tried doing in the same way, but draw.io use a api to convert vsd file to some format, which i am not able to understand and stuck there.

Expected result would be able to import .vsd file in grapheditor tool of mxgraph

Comment: As far as I know, .vsdx files are xml-formatted, could you post an example of the .vsdx file you want to import?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/diagramly/vsdx/importer.js which has source code for vsdx import